# VSTS Test, JUnit and the VSTS Rest API

Tags: xml, junit, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

**Note**: please keep in mind that I have never worked with VSTS Test so some of my comments may me wrong. I have worked with the rest of VSTS extensively.

I have a task to publish some JUnit test results XML into VSTS online Test:
[image]

My tests are run within an Ubuntu Docker container so I want to use the VSTS rest API to publish them. Here is the rest API documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/?view=vsts-rest-5.0

```
POST https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.0-preview.5
```

Which works fine but the POST body example is json:

```
[
 {
  "testCaseTitle": "VerifyWebsiteTheme",
  "automatedTestName": 
  "FabrikamFiber.WebSite.TestClass.VerifyWebsiteTheme",
  "priority": 1,
  "outcome": "Passed"
 },
 {
  "testCaseTitle": "VerifyWebsiteLinks",
  "automatedTestName": 
  "FabrikamFiber.WebSite.TestClass.VerifyWebsiteLinks",
  "priority": 2,
  "outcome": "Failed",
  "associatedBugs": [
  {
    "id": 30
  }
]
```

}
]

Whereas, my tester and his test output is giving me XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuite errors="10" failures="0" name="pytest" skips="12" tests="53" time="16.073">    
  <testcase classname="tests.test_api" file="tests/test_api.py" line="5" name="test_GETNotFound" time="0.4054398536682129"></testcase>    
  <testcase classname="tests.test_api" file="tests/test_api.py" line="10" name="test_POSTBadRequest[]" time="0.41185760498046875"></testcase>
  <testcase classname="tests.test_api" file="tests/test_api.py" line="10" name="test_POSTBadRequest[req1]" time="0.48476719856262207"></testcase>
  <testcase classname="tests.test_api" file="tests/test_api.py" line="10" name="test_POSTBadRequest[{}]" time="0.44095635414123535"></testcase>
  <testcase classname="tests.test_api" file="tests/test_api.py" line="10" name="test_POSTBadRequest[TEST]" time="0.4718012809753418"></testcase>
  <testcase classname="tests.test_azureFileService" file="tests/test_azureFileService.py" line="0" name="test_readFilesDirs" time="0.22459125518798828"></testcase>
</testsuite>
```

I have no idea how I get from a JUnit XML file into the desired way of doing it with the VSTS Rest API.

Would love some guidance.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: 
Copy the test results out of your container and use the `Publish Test Results` task, which can parse JUnit formatted XML test results. `docker cp containerName:/path/to/testresults.xml ./testresults.xml` should do the trick.

Option 2: Write a simple program to parse the test results and output a JSON document, then run it in your container.

I'd say Option 1 is better, but that's just my opinion. I've done exactly that with test results from other tools.

Comment: thanks for your tips. I actually went with option 11 before I even read you comment. My lack of Linux confidence was stopping me from attempting to use the Publish Test Results task as I could not get the syntax of the pathing correct. I have now got it to work and it works great. Thanks